# Is this a correct description of the BPS monopole of charge $1$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gauge-theory, higgs-bundles

I am reading the book "The Geometry and Dynamics of Magnetic Monopoles", by M.F. Atiyah and N.J. Hitchin, and I got to this part:

"... let $H$ be the Hopf line bundle over $S^2$ and form the vector bundle $H^k \oplus H^{-k}$ over $S^2$. Now extend this radially to $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\} = S^2 \times \mathbb{R}^+$. This gives us an $SU(2)$-bundle $E_k$ with connection and Higgs field on $\mathbb{R}^3 - \{0\}$ which is acted on naturally by $SO(3)$."

I am trying to understand the previous part my way. I have a guess as to what the BPS monopole of charge $1$ may be and would like to ask if this guess is correct or not.

Edit: my first attempt wasn't right. I will now completely edit my guess.

One may think of $S^2$ as the following homogeneous space:

$$S^2 = SU(2) / U(1),$$

where $U(1)$ is the following subgroup of $SU(2)$, consisting of matrices of the form
$$ \rho(\lambda) := \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda^{-1} \end{pmatrix}, $$
where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, with $|\lambda| = 1$.

Consider the trivial bundle $S^2 \times \mathfrak{su}(2)$ over $S^2$. Note that the right invariant Maurer-Cartan $1$-form $dg g^{-1}$ on $SU(2)$, at some point $g \in SU(2)$, restricts to a linear map from the subspace $E_g$ of $T_g(SU(2))$ which is orthogonal to the $U(1)$ orbit of $g$ (with respect to a bi-invariant metric on $SU(2)$), and, being right-invariant, this descends to a $1$-form on $S^2$ with values in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, which we denote by $A$.

Finally, let
$$ x_0 = \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{pmatrix}. $$
We define $\Phi: S^2 \to \mathfrak{su}(2)$ by
$$\Phi(gU(1)) = g x_0 g^{-1},$$
which is well defined.

Note that $\Phi$ defines a map of degree $1$ from $S^2$ to the sphere in $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

My guess is that $(A, \Phi)$ defines a BPS monopole of magnetic charge $1$ on $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{ 0 \}$. Strictly speaking, I have only defined $(A, \Phi)$ on $S^2$, but I think that if one extends $(A, \Phi)$ to $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus \{0\}$ properly (with the right "radial" dependence), one may then get a solution of the Bogomolny equations:
$$ F = *D \Phi, $$
with $D$ being the connection defined by $A$, $F$ the curvature of $A$ and $*$ being the Hodge star on differential forms defined on Euclidean $3$-dimensional space (minus the origin).

Is this correct please?